# How do I start creating role-specfic commands?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I want to be able to give the role '[ADMIN]' (that's how it is in the server) the permission to use the command `${prefix}hall` to make the discord bot display an embed without any of the other roles being allowed to do so.

I have no idea how. Here's my code so far:

```
if(cmd === `${prefix}hall`) {
  let botembed = new Discord.RichEmbed();
  return;
}

bot.login(botconfig.token);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post your relevant code directly here. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

To make the command role-specific, just check if the member has the role with [`guildMember.roles.has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/has).
To build the embed you can look at the [Discord.js Guide](https://discordjs.guide/#/popular-topics/miscellaneous-examples?id=sending-an-embed).
To get your role you can use [`guild.roles.find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=find).

Here's what you can try:

```
//'message' is the message with the command, the one you're replying to.
let admin_role = guild.roles.find("name", "[ADMIN]"); //this gets your role
if (cmd == `${prefix}hall` && message.member.has(admin_role.id)) { //this checks the command & the role
  let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed();
  //embed stuff...
  message.channel.send(embed); //this replies with the embed
}
```

Comment: You can also use `if (message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === 'Name Here'))` or `if(message.guild.member(client.user).hasPermission("PERM HERE"))` for the bot and `if(message.guild.member(message.author).hasPermission("PERM HERE"))` for a user. Discord permission name list [Here](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/permissions).